# What is the difference between "wrapping" a key and encrypting?

Tags: encryption, rsa, key-wrap

I wanted to implement a way to generate an RSA public/private key pair and protect the private key with a password.

Looking into the Web crypto api, I thought the `wrapKey`/`unwrapKey` pair was the way to go. But then I got confused, and the documentation is not really helping because it seems to assume you know everything about cryptography.

What I'm really stumped on is, why do we need a `wrapKey`/`unwrapKey` in the first place? Can't you generate a symmetric key and encrypt the RSA private key with the symmetric key, and later decrypt it with the same symmetric key?

Comment: One other point of interest is that AES-KW doesn't need an IV (as noted here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63191/webcrypto-aes-gcm-vs-aes-kw-for-key-wrapping).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get nausea every time I look at the WebCrypto API documentation, so if all you get is confusion, consider yourself lucky.

From what I can tell by reading the [W3C Web Cryptography API recommendation of 2017](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), in particular the [§19 Algorithm Overview table](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#algorithm-overview), **the *only* difference is that the `AES-KW` algorithm of [RFC 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394) supports wrapKey/unwrapKey but not encrypt/decrypt.**

The intent appears to be that you use wrapKey/unwrapKey when you know the plaintext is itself a short uniform random octet string, but encrypt/decrypt if it has any other structure to its distribution; then if you attempt to use encrypt/decrypt with AES-KW, the API will noisily fail because you might be trying to use it with structured data, which AES-KW is unfit to conceal.

**For *all other* documented encryption schemes, public-key or secret-key, wrapKey/unwrapKey just defers to encrypt/decrypt.**  So there's no idea of KEM at all, which simultaneously generates a key *and* encapsulates it for you.  One can hope that they will introduce a KEM API in the next version of the specification, since with NIST PQCRYPTO it appears the world is finally, nearly two decades after [Shoup introduced the concept](http://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf), converging on it as the basic way to do public-key encryption.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Also it's great to know I'm not the crazy one to be confused!

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage, why is AES-KW unfit to conceal structure and where in the Web Cryptography API spec does it say that it's supposed to fail for e.g. an RSA-OAEP private key?